# What causes this black line across the edge of my photos?

Tags: troubleshooting, nikon-d5100

I'm not a pro photographer. I've been using a Nikon D5100 for a long time. But lately, I'm facing a problem that while taking a picture, there's a black line along the edge of my photos. See the sample photo below.

[image]

What is causing this, and is this something I can fix?

Comment: Is this on the same place and size on all photos?

Comment: Additionally, does this occur at all shutter speeds?

Comment: Is it just me, or is there something odd in the part of the image that includes his foot? It seems disproportionately long.

Answer (score 3):

Likely your shutter curtain that doesn't make a full travel. Your camera needs to be serviced.

Answer (score -2):

You have exceeded the maximum shutter speed allowed by the camera body (sync-speed). What was your shutter speed?

Comment: This is true only if flash is involved! and IMHO if flash is involved the size of the band will be bigger

Comment: Welcome to the community Kosala! I'm afraid that I'm going to downvote your first contribution - as there's no evidence that flash was used. No shadows, no catchlights...and an overcast day to account for the soft lighting. Unless you have other points to back your claim...in which case I'll gladly retract my vote.